How to add a special character to A Password Validation Form
I'm trying to make a password validation in javascript, I found several questions here using the same example from W3Schools and I followed all the examples with results but it doesn't make sure you enter a special character. It does check if you have one and make a green checkmark but it does not require one. I am pretty sure nobody knows there is still a problem everyone is missing. I am sure it is only the html pattern. I don't know how to force at least 1 special character in the html pattern. here is the pattern I have so far: pattern="(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"


var myInput = document.getElementById("password");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");
var special = document.getElementById("special");

// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.onblur = function() {
    document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
myInput.onkeyup = function() {
// Validate lowercase letters
var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
letter.classList.remove("invalid");
letter.classList.add("valid");
} else {
letter.classList.remove("valid");
letter.classList.add("invalid");
}

// Validate capital letters
var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
capital.classList.remove("invalid");
capital.classList.add("valid");
} else {
capital.classList.remove("valid");
capital.classList.add("invalid");
}

// Validate numbers
var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
number.classList.remove("invalid");
number.classList.add("valid");
} else {
number.classList.remove("valid");
number.classList.add("invalid");
}

// Validate length
if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
length.classList.remove("invalid");
length.classList.add("valid");
} else {
length.classList.remove("valid");
length.classList.add("invalid");
}

// Validate special
var specialcharacters = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/g;
if(myInput.value.match(specialcharacters)) {
special.classList.remove("invalid");
special.classList.add("valid");
} else {
special.classList.remove("valid");
special.classList.add("invalid");
}
}
<style>
#message {
display:none;
background: #EFEFEF;
color: #000;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0px;
text-align:left;
width:100%;
}
#message p {
padding: 2px 35px 2px 60px;
font-size: 18px;
}
/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
color: green;
}
.valid:before {
position: relative;
left: -20px;
content: "✔";
}
/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
color: red;
}
.invalid:before {
position: relative;
left: -20px;
content: "✖";
color: red;
}
</style>
<form>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required minlength="8" maxlength="32" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}">
</form>

<div id="message">
<div style="padding-top:8px;"></div>
<h2 style="padding-left:40px;font-size:19px;text-decoration:underline;font-weight:650;color:#333;">Password Requirements:</h2>
<p id="letter" class="invalid"><span style="font-weight:600;font-size:17px;">A lowercase letter</span></p>
<p id="capital" class="invalid"><span style="font-weight:600;font-size:17px;">A capital letter</span></p>
<p id="number" class="invalid"><span style="font-weight:600;font-size:17px;">A number</span></p>
<p id="special" class="invalid"><span style="font-weight:600;font-size:17px;">A special character</span></p>
<p id="length" class="invalid"><span style="font-weight:600;font-size:17px;">A minimum of 8 characters</span></p>
</div>



Added (Edited)
I narrowed it down to the html pattern. this pattern almost works: (?=.\W)(?=.\d)(?=.[ a-z])(?=.[A-Z]).{8,} the (?=.\W) forces every other special character except an underscore. It does allow a space which I like. Any idea how I can add an _ to the (?=.\W) or another way to do it please?

I figured it out. Change the html regex pattern to:
pattern="(?=.*[\W_])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,32}"

the \W includes all special characters excluding the underscore so I added _ after \W
If the checkmark or X do not show up properly (without color), use another font, Arial works great.
Here is a php code you can use to verify it matches the pattern which will make sure the form is not altered to change the pattern:
    $pattern = '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\W_]).{8,32}$/';
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $_POST['password'])) {
            $msg = 'Please do not edit the code!';   // Error Message
            $success = 0;    // Form has error(s)!
        }

Also, add maximum to minimum in the javascript code like this:
// Validate length
    if(myInput.value.length >= 8 && myInput.value.length <= 32) {

And, change the html requirements:
<p id="length" class="invalid"><span style="font-weight:600;font-size:17px;">Between 8 and 32 characters</span></p>


You can create an input element for each type of character and then validate against all the input elements with a pattern attribute. As the user type in the password field, the value will be copied to all the other input elements. They are hidden, and have no name attribute (important, so that the field is not included in the submitting of the form). But still, all the required fields need to be valid before the form will be submitted. Now each pattern is simple.
Like you identified yourself the underscore is included in the word character \w and not as a non-word/a special character \W. So, you basically need to add the underscore to the pattern of the "special character" input element. But if you would also like to avid any white space characters you need an explicit expression of all the characters that you consider "special". If you collect all the special characters, the list looks like this:
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
To avoid any issues with some of these characters having a function in a regular expression, you can convert the characters to hex code:
\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e
and use that in the pattern for the special characters.


document.forms.form01.password.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  form.querySelectorAll('input[pattern]')
    .forEach(input => input.value = e.target.value);
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(...new FormData(e.target));
});
form[name="form01"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

input[pattern] {
  display: none;
}

li:has(input:valid) {
  list-style: "✔";
  color: green;
}

li:has(input:invalid) {
  list-style: "✖";
  color: red;
}
<form name="form01">
  <label>Username:<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required></label>
  <label>Password:<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required></label>
  <h2>Password Requirements:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><input pattern=".*[a-z]+.*" required>A lowercase letter</li>
    <li><input pattern=".*[A-Z]+.*" required>A capital letter</li>
    <li><input pattern=".*\d+.*" required>A number</li>
    <li><input pattern=".*[\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e]+.*" required>A special character</li>
    <li><input pattern=".{8,}" required>A minimum of 8 characters</li>
  </ul>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>




Sorry, I did say, I just need to add something to my current html pattern, to force 1 single special character and allow multiple special characters. (but the \W does not count underscores and I need that included.

@Antarctica-UFO I missed that. I updated my answer so that the underscore is included as a special character. As I understand it underscore is the only odd character in that sense.

your method did not work for me. you go to another input and it starts the thing over again. Please look at my answer, it works awesome!

@Antarctica-UFO When you add another input element to the form, the event listener for the input event needs to be more specific. Now, the event listener is on document.forms.form01.password.
